# How to modify paths to work for every user? (Python)

Tags: python

Ok I know this is probably a very simple question to answer but I don't know how to find the answer (I don't know the technical words used for this concept,etc)

I have a folder path like this one. Obviously where I've written "MYUSERNAME" I'd normally write my real username

`C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\Test`

I'm using that path for a python code that I've previously compiled, and I want my friends to use that code without having to change the code. How do I automatically fill that "MYUSERNAME" with the username of the current user?
I've tried writing "User" and such in there but nothing works. Even if I have to add a few lines of code I don't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Path` library in Python can probably help you out here. For example, the below snippet provides the home path of the logged in user:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
myPath = os.path.join(home, "Desktop", "Test")
#This gives the required path, i.e `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\Test` for the logged in user running the code
```

There are a few caveats here, and the above snippet doesn't work as expected if the user is logged on to a domain on windows and has their profile home folder set in active directory. However, your question specifies no such constraint so this should be good enough.

Comment: Ok I'm very new to Python. I want to ask a thing to clarify. The "home" part is simply the "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME" then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use relative paths. More info: [difference between relative and absolute](https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-and-relative-paths-3466467).